# Which is better for page speed, a cached global css file, or loading the global css internally?

Tags: css, performance, html

For the sake of page speed I am addressing how the sites css is loaded. Originally the site called several css files on each page. I took the standard approach, combine and minify all css into one file, leverage browser caching and use a CDN. This offers much improvement.

My next step is to separate the global css from the per page css to avoid loading any unused css. My original goal would be to call one minified css file on each page that holds the global css rules, and output the per page css internally in the `<head>` section of the page.

The global css file will be cacheable by the browser and reusable for each page but does count as render blocking css and an additionally http request.

Would it be better for page speed to output the global styles internally in the `<head>` section of each page to avoid an additional http request even though it will sacrifice the global styles being reusable browser cached css?

EDIT: I am using PHP and caching the pages, so it is not a question of what is easier to develop, it is only a question about the performance of the output (HTML / CSS).

Answer (score 2):

**It's complicated...**

Including the styles in the head means they won't be cached and that you're transferring more than needed to render the page. Additionally, external CSS imported via `<link>`s are pipelined, so that you're not waiting on one to complete before fetching the next. The result, is that usually two 100kb sheets will transfer and indeed render faster than one 200kb file.

Of course, certain network issues like slow DNS can affect results, but generally, with non overloaded CPU and decent bandwidth and low ping times, pipelines increases page speed, especially if one or more pipes are cached.

Putting the rules inline in the `<head>` could also give gzip more work per page, which would lower bandwidth compared to something that can be shrunk once and cached.

In short, it somewhat depends on users, nets, and code, but without mis-configuring or bad hardware, using a global import should be faster than shipping inline.

One last note: if you just need a small amount of CSS, it's faster to store it inline in the head. For example, i've found that `body { opacity: 0; transition: 500ms opacity;}` can help hide FOUC better than an external sheet under more conditions, so for such UX optimizations, a little bit of CSS inline is highly warranted.